# Linear operators and weak star topology.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\mathbb{L} = \operatorname{span}\{\delta_t : t \in [0, 1]\} $, where $\delta_t \in C[0,1]^*, \delta_t(f) = f(t).$ How to prove that the linear functional 
$G(f) = \int_0^1 f(t) dt$ belongs to weak* closedness of $\mathbb{L}$?

Comment: Write the integral as a limit of Riemann sums using e.g. left endpoints.

Comment: It is worth posting this as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The span $\mathbb L$ of $\lbrace \delta_t: t\in [0,1]\rbrace$ is in fact weak$^*$ dense in $C[0,1]^*$. This follows from Hahn-Banach because the dual of $(C[0,1],$weak$^*)$ is $C[0,1]$ (meaning that every $\Phi$ in the dual is of the form $\Phi(u)=u(f)$ for some $f\in C[01]$ -- this is so for every normed or even locally convex space) and every $f\in C[0,1]$ vanishing on $\mathbb L$ is obviously $0$.